# How to print all console output after a match is found in a DOS batch file?

Tags: batch-file, dos

Using DOS batch syntax, I need to wait until a pattern shows up in console output, and then print everything after that (or at least print N lines after the match). How can I do that? (Something like grep +A in Unix). I can simply do this, to get the pattern:

```
run_my_command | findstr "my_pattern"
```

But looking at findstr manual, it doesn't seem there is a switch to print everything (or N lines after the pattern). I am not an expert in DOS batch, so if you have ideas, please be direct.

EDIT:

Here is the last part from my output (i.e. There are LOTs of lines before these lines, But all I am interested in, is the results of the tests, i.e. everything after "Results :" which is bold)

> ...
>
> ...
>
> 21:23:26.332 [Thread-4] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter -
>   Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'ehcache'
>
> 21:23:26.332 [Thread-4] INFO  o.s.c.e.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean -
>   Shutting down EhCache CacheManager
>
> 21:23:26.332 [Thread-4] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager -
>   CacheManager already shutdown
>
> **Results : Tests in error:    ReceiptsSearchRequestBuilderTest.testCreateSearchRequest_loadDate:97 »
>   IllegalArgument   ReceiptLineControllerTest.testFind:26 » NullPointer
>   Tests run: 229, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0**
>
> **[INFO] ----------------------------------**
>
> **[INFO] BUILD FAILURE**
>
> **[INFO] ----------------------------------**
>
> **[INFO] Total time: 23.213 s**
>
> **[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-03T14:23:26-07:00**
>
> **[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/453M**
>
> **[INFO] -------------------------------**

EDIT:

Here is my script. When I don't redirect to %log%, it only prints the text after my pattern, which is what I want. But when I redirect it to %log%, the log file contains ALL the text (stderr correctly gets dumped to null as well).

```
@echo OFF

SET MAVEN_PROFILE=ie
SET root_dir="%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MyFolder"
SET log=%root_dir%/log.txt

powershell -c "$txt=(&mvn -P %MAVEN_PROFILE% -Dtest=LoginTest test > %log% 2> null) -join \"`r`n\"; $i=$txt.indexof('Results :'); if($i -ge 0) { $j=$txt.lastindexof(\"`n\",$i); write-host $txt.substring([math]::max(0,$j+1))}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-liner using powershell which you can run from your batch file, it takes 10 seconds to find a string at the end of 120MB output:

```
powershell -c "$txt=(&your_console_app -with -arguments) -join \"`r`n\"; $i=$txt.indexof('string_to_search_for'); if($i -ge 0) { $j=$txt.lastindexof(\"`n\",$i); $txt.substring([math]::max(0,$j+1)) }"
```

- Replace `your_console_app -with -arguments` and `string_to_search_for` accordingly. If those contain doublequotes escape them as `\"`.
- Add `pause` on a new line to keep the console window open if needed.

---

An example using your actual command line which outputs to standard output redirected to a file:

```
@echo OFF

SET MAVEN_PROFILE=ie
SET root_dir="%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MyFolder"
SET log=%root_dir%/log.txt

powershell -c "$txt=(&mvn -P %MAVEN_PROFILE% -Dtest=LoginTest test 2>nul) -join \"`r`n\"; $i=$txt.indexof('Results :'); if($i -ge 0) { $j=$txt.lastindexof(\"`n\",$i); $txt.substring([math]::max(0,$j+1)) }" >results.txt
```

Alternatively you can write to the file directly from within powershell code:

```
powershell -c "$txt=(&mvn -P %MAVEN_PROFILE% -Dtest=LoginTest test 2>nul) -join \"`r`n\"; $i=$txt.indexof('Results :'); if($i -ge 0) { $j=$txt.lastindexof(\"`n\",$i); $txt.substring([math]::max(0,$j+1)) | out-file 'results.txt' }"
```

Comment: Great. This works when and it prints only what I want to the console. How can I make the redirect work also? (Please see my code above in the original question). I can see the log files get created, so it seems like your command can resolve the %log%, but the problem is the log contains ALL console output (instead of just the output after the pattern)

Comment: Added an actual example. Note that there's no need to redirect to %log% because powershell reads stdout of the command. When you redirected it the command sent its full output to log file and then powershell saw nothing.

Comment: Ah! Makes sense. The script works successfully now. Thank you very much!

Comment: ok, I see a problem with this now. It does work when the console output is small (i.e. It works when I only run 1 test. Console output is not too much so it seems to work fine). But when I tried it for our test suite as a whole (56 tests at the moment) the command seems to never finish, so the script never terminates :(
Thoughts?

Comment: And what happens if you run the entire test suite with output redirection to a file from the command line: `mvn .......... >logfile.txt`?

Comment: hmm... Looks like maybe the script fails when I run the whole test suite, but maybe for a different reason. Not sure yet. I'll post an update soon.

Comment: OK, I had a mis-configuration in my test-suite. I confirmed the above solution works successfully :)
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean pattern shows up? And where you want to find? Since you want to print N lines or everything after that, I assume you are searching for a word in a text file instead of pattern.

```
@echo off
set /p word = What word/pattern you are searching for? ^>
set bool = 0

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (Text.txt) do (
    if %%a == %word% set bool = 1
    if %bool% == 1 echo %%a
)
```

This script only print everything after the word you're looking for is found.

Comment: dark fang, I am running a command that produces a ton of output. I want to ignore most of the output and basically only print the whatever is written after my pattern. (eventually redirect it into another file and save). So I am not working with a static (fixed size) text file. How can I use your script to make it work with a real time command output?

Comment: simply redirect the command's output to a temporary file: `run_my_command >text.txt`

Comment: dark fang, I am running a maven command that builds our project. The output is about 120 MB (and that's after I use the --quiet switch to decrease the output). I replaced the "Text.txt" part of your script with "mvn install" and also with " 'mvn install' ", but they don't seem to work. Is there a way make it work for my case?  
wOxxOm, yes I would do that eventually, but first I need to be able to discard most of the output and only capture the output that I am interested in.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Maven, but does "mvn install" can be called in cmd? If it can, try replace `cmd /c mvn install` with Text.txt. Since batch is slow, I don't think it can be done quickly

Comment: Yes, it can. But it didn't work. All I see is a CMD window that flashes (The maven command should take a couple of minutes to finish at least, but when I run the script, all I see in a flash of a CMD window, and then nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you need to execute both parts connected via a pipe, like in your example. Although it is possible to write the right-side pipe process in pure Batch, batch file processing have synchronization problems when reading from a pipe, so we need to use a different language.

[JScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yek4tbz0(v=vs.84).aspx) is a programming language more powerful than Batch that is available in all Windows versions from XP on, and it is very easy to combine both Batch and JScript code in the same *hybrid script*:

**EDIT**: There was a `@` missing in line one. Fixed

```
@set @Batch=1 /*
@echo off
run_my_command | CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
goto :EOF    */

// JScript section

var lineFound = false, numOfLines = N;
while ( ! WScript.Stdin.AtEndOfStream ) {
   line = WScript.Stdin.ReadLine();
   if ( ! lineFound  &&  line.indexOf("my_pattern") >= 0 ) lineFound = true;
   if ( lineFound  &&  numOfLines ) {
      WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(line);
      --numOfLines;
   }
}
```

Save previous code in a file with .bat extension; you need to adjust a couple details in the code.

Comment: Please, edit your question and insert a _small_ section of the output data (10 or 15 lines), and the pattern search, so I can do my own tests. Note that "It didn't work" describe nothing... When complete the changes, post a comment here as advice.

Comment: Updated my post with sample output.

Comment: Ops! There was a `@` missing before the "Batch" name in line 1: `@set @Batch=1 /*`. Please, fix it and try again... **`:(`**

Comment: Aacini, when I try it, I get this error:
`Microsoft JScript compilation error: Expected ';' `

From the last line of the script (at the end of your code). I tried putting a ; after "%~F0" but then I got "myfile.bat cannot be found" error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar idea to Aacini's answer, except it uses an already written hybrid JScript/batch utility called [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) that provides sophisticated regular expression text processing capabilities to batch. JREPL.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

To skip output and begin printing with the first line that begins with `Results :`

```
yourCommand | jrepl "^Results :[\s\S]*" "$0" /jmatch /m
```

To print only the lines that begin with `Results :`, plus the next 4 lines (5 total)

```
yourCommand | jrepl "^Results :(.*\n){0,4}.*$" "$0" /jmatch /m
```

Both commands above use the `/M` multi-line option, which means the entire output must be loaded into memory. Nothing will print until the command completes. This could be a problem if the output is multiple gigabytes, or if it is long running, and you want to see output as soon as possible.

With a bit more code, and user supplied JScript, it is possible to process and print each line independently - with no delay, and no size limitation:

To print everything starting with the first line beginning with `Results :`

```
yourCommand | jrepl "^Results :.*|^.*" "go=true;$0|go?$0:false" /jmatch /t "|" /jbeg "var go=false"
```

To print only lines that begin with `Results :`, plus the next 4 lines (5 total)

```
yourCommand | jrepl "^Results :.*|^.*" "go=5;$0|(--go>0)?$0:false" /jmatch /t "|" /jbeg "var go=0"
```